Is it possible to wrap an Angular app as web component in react
We have a react + capacitor app, and now we want the different application to be imported as mini app, like example an angular app that help a user to sign in and sign out we need that to be imported in our react app as mini app so once the app open we can show that sign in and out in our home page.
Is it possible with react + capacitor app

Maybe you can use the compiled version of angular and share data through session storage or local storage.

@masteronin99 i want angular app to be used in react + capacitor app, my motive is to load different mini app to react app as web component

you could probably use an iframe.  It should have a completely separate context in a modern browser.

No bro, if i want to use iframe i would have already done that but i dont want to use iframe or webview i want to use miniapp as component

You can, since angular comps can be built to web components. It doesn't matter if they are used in react or anywhere else. Is there a specific problem you have with this?

No, there is no specific problem, i used it with react app and it works fine but i dont want to use dist folder generated files in react, instead i want to use it as npm dependency, or a kind of sdk what will be integrated with react app and works smoothly
